# Unformat major minor

Tags: java, oracle10g

I am working on java code. and when i was deploying my code in Oracle server,it shows unformatted  major minor exception 51.0. in console and war file is not deployed in server.

how to get rid of this problem.?

Comment: It is a java version issue, see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-error

Answer (score 1):

You have to set proper compile version. In eclipse, There is option to enable from properties by right click project. click `project->properties->Java Compiler->   Change level above 1.5` and clean project again.